# Update error in Laravel: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App\Category' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I am new to laravel and I am trying to update my table using the following code. But receiving the following error

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App\Category' not found

My Code is

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use App\Category;
class CategoryController extends Controller
{


    public function UpdateCategory()
    {
        $category = App\Category::find(3);

        $category->name = 'Women';

        $category->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have already defined `use App\Category;` at the top as a your model path, try `$category = Category::find(3);` only if your model is in `App` folder! No need to redefine it when you update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use App\Category;
```

> you already include your model in controller. So you dont need to include once again

```
$category = Category::find(3);
```

> simply use this

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$category = Category::find(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Change**

```
$category = App\Category::find(3);
```

**To**

```
$category = Category::find(3);
```